# Create navbar for login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react";
function Navbar() {
  return <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">React Routing  Example</Link>
  <div className="ml-auto">
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/home">Home</Link></li>
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/service">Services</Link></li>
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
}

export default Navbar;
```

then not showing navbar in browser showing error

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 
        
       Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

creating Navabar for  lofin form

Comment: You've a typo. `React` doesn't export any `Link` component. You likely meant `import { Link } from "react-router-dom";`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `Link` from `react-router-dom`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
function Navbar() {
  return <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">React Routing  Example</Link>
  <div className="ml-auto">
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/home">Home</Link></li>
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/service">Services</Link></li>
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You import `Link` from react that doesn't exist in react

you should use `react-router` for to use 'Link'.

Answer (score 0):

You should import { Link } from "react-router-dom", instead of importing it from "react" as it doestn't exist in "react". You can read more about the "react-router-dom" here https://reactrouter.com/en/main

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
function Navbar() {
  return <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">React Routing  Example</Link>
  <div className="ml-auto">
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/home">Home</Link></li>
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/service">Services</Link></li>
          <li className="nav-list"><Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
}

export default Navbar;
```